# Regex - find all whitespaces and ignore hyphen separated words in multiline string

Tags: regex, re-python

I want to create a regex pattern which finds whitespaces and ignore hyphen seperated words.

The basic rule is to find any subsequent whitespaces(`[\s]+`), and do **not** find whitespaces where the pattern is:

`[\S]+-[\s]+[\S]+` (The pattern of which i don't want to match the whitespaces)

Any other whitespaces should match.

Matched intervals should include whitespaces only, not other characters.

**For example:**

> abc abc

should match at position 3-4.

> abc
>       def

should match from the end of abc to start of def.

> abc-
>
> def

should not match.

> abc -
>
> def

should match at 3-4, 5-6.

The searched string is multiline and has many occurences of whitespaces, and i want to find them all in a single search.

Tried many different patterns (with negative lookahead and lookbehind) but none was able to apply for all cases.

Using python builtin `re` module.

It is possible to do in two searches:

1. search for all occurences of `[\s]+`
2. search for all occurences of `[\S]+-([\s]+)[\S]+`
3. remove matches of the group in (2) from matches in (1)

Is it possible to do in a single search?

Comment: Try `r'(?<=[^\s-])\s+(?=\S)|(?<=\S)\s+(?=[^\s-])'` or `r'(?<=[^\s-])\s+(?=[^\s-])'`

Comment: Maybe this is the way, but still not working. https://regex101.com/r/qSZq9P/7 see this example. This should not match, similar to example 3 in the question

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/qSZq9P/9, `r'(?<=[^\s-])\s+(?=[^\s-])'`

Comment: This fix the problem above, now string like: "dsa - dsa" should match twice in the spaces and does not in current pattern. As in example (4).

Comment: Maybe `(?<!-)\s+|(?<=\s-)\s+` https://regex101.com/r/RqNmpx/1

Comment: Try `r'(?<![^-\s]-(?=\s+[^-\s]))\s+'`

Comment: @Thefourthbird matched for: "abc-  def" with multiple spaces.

Comment: Is does not match that, should it? https://regex101.com/r/SZJ4pp/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird see this https://regex101.com/r/qSZq9P/10. It shouldn't match it.

Comment: Please see https://ideone.com/VhOatC, not sure what code and real input you have, it might be much simpler if we had more details.

Comment: My inputs are raw text extracted from documents crawled from the web, so many cases may happen. I wish to split the text to words, and maintain words which were seperated by hyphen in some document formats like pdf. For example Hello may appear in the document as Hel-\n\n\n\nlo, So if the regex will find this new line chars, the word Hello will be splitted in half to two words -> "Hel" and "lo".

Comment: So, you want something like `re.findall(r'[^\s-]+(?:-\s+[^\s-]+)*', sample)`?

Comment: This matches all the normal characters well, a solution that matches all the whitespaces is preferd (Because of the algorithm that is used after that). @WiktorStribiżew. If we go that way, the only thing that does not work is a hyphen surrounded by spaces, should match also. e.g ' - '.

Comment: But [the solution I suggested already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508076/regex-find-all-whitespaces-and-ignore-hyphen-separated-words-in-multiline-stri?noredirect=1#comment107044094_60508076) matches them, see https://ideone.com/Dp8b4k

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You pattern fails for "abc-\n\n\ndef". This should not match, see https://ideone.com/NpA7HJ

Comment: You seem to want to perform some split operation, but this requires a regex that supports lookbehinds of variable length, or a SKIP-FAIL regex, and Python `re` does not support those. If you are willing to follow that path, you must install the PyPi regex module with `pip install regex`. If you want to continue the journey with `re`, you need to change the logic, and use the simple technique that proved useful at all times: match and capture what you need and only match what you do not need.See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/snD7h1).

Comment: Using the `pip install regex` module is an option. What would be the pattern then?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(?<![\s\-])[\s](?!\-\s\n)
```

1. `(?<![\s\-])` not look space after space and - : (negative look behind)
2. `(?!\-\s\n)` not look space before - space and new line : (negative look ahead)

**Edited:**

Try this:

```
(?<![\s])[\s+](?!\-\s\n)(?!\n{2})
```

After review your sample data, some of it contains double new line so:

1. `(?<![\s])` not look after space
2. `(?!\-\s\n)` not look before dash, space, and newline
3. `(?!\n{2})` not look before double newline

Comment: Does not work for: "abc - abc". Two matches  should be produced. One before the '-' and one after.

Comment: After edit - fails for "abc\n\ndef". It should match any whitespaces, except those specified in the question.

Comment: after all I thought it only can be done with multiple step regex because your data have slightly same conditions between the accepted space and not. lets wait may be somebody have another solution.